# Display matching fields foreignkey with primary key

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.0

I've both table in MySQL

> Forwards_signs

```
+----+-------------+----------+
+ ID + Forward_id  + sign_id  +
+----+-------------+----------+
+ 4  +     2       +    2     +
+ 5  +     2       +    3     +
+ 4  +     2       +    14    +
+----+-------------+----------+
```

> Signs table

```
+----+-------------+---------------------------------+
+ ID +   Signno    +         Gejala                  +
+----+-------------+---------------------------------+
+ 2  +   SIG002    + Bulu rontok berlebihan          +
+ 3  +   SIG003    + Terdapat kebotakan              +
+ 14 +   SIG004    + Bercak putih seperti ketombe    +
+ 8  +   SIG008    + Terdapat kerak keropeng         +
+ 9  +   SIG009    + Warna bulu pucat dan kotor      +
+----+-------------+---------------------------------+
```

I'm used framework CakePHP with relation hasMany() in table method.
the goal that I want to join with matching both table, foreign key will match to Primary Key,

the result that I'm imagine is below

```
Forwards_signs table     Signs table
+----+-----------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
+ ID + sign_id         +  ID  +  Signno  +  Gejala                         +
+----+-----------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
+ 4  +    2            +  2   +  SIG002  +  Bulu rontok berlebihan         +
+ 5  +    3            +  3   +  SIG003  +  Terdapat kebotakan             +
+ 4  +    14           +  14  +  SIG014  +  Bercak putih seperti ketombe   +
+----+-----------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
```

thanx for everyone and I hope for help my trouble ..

Comment: This is a textbook case of associations and containment. Have you gone through the tutorial?

Comment: yes, I'm having read book tutorial and success implement  and displaying result relation hasMany, hasOne, and belongsTo. The implement before is showing all record is successfull, next I want to experiment to show spesific record, matching with foreinkey, if it doesn't match they doe'snt display

Comment: So, you've used `find('all')` with containment successfully? Just use `get()` with containment to get a single record instead of a bunch. If that's not enough help, please share with us what code you have written so far and describe what's not working about it, and we can address those specifics.

Comment: thanks for your help, I'll experiment again with functiion get(), thanx for your support me

Comment: Solved? if y, I encourage you to answer your own question with proper editing. :)